# angularjs very simple yes/no boolean select directive not binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write what must be the simplest angular directive which displays a Yes/No select list and is bound to a model containing a boolean value. Unfortunately the existing value is never preselected. My directive reads

```
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<select class="form-control"><option value="true">Yes</option><option value="false">No</option></select>',
        scope: {
              ngModel: '='
        }
  }
```

and I am calling the directive as

```
<yesno ng-model="brand.is_anchor"></yesno>
```

The select options display and the generated HTML reads as

```
<select class="form-control ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" ng-model="brand.is_anchor">
    <option value="? boolean:false ?"></option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

The initial value of the bound model is "false" but it always displays an empty option and per the first option listed in the generated HTML.

Can anybody please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not use `<option>` tags with angularjs.
Use the angular "ng-options" directive on the select element instead.

```
<select ng-options="..."></select>
```

See angular docs for it:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Your problems will be solved using this instead.

Comment: yes your answer is write then if we used "ng-selected" what will be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I now understand that you can only compare strings unless you are using ng-options(?) however, I only wanted to bind a boolean value, not an model. After implementing ng-options my bounded value always ends up something like {id:4, label:"Yes"}. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: you can tell angular which value to use from your object using the "as" and "track by" keywords.
for example
ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in items track by item.id"
for more details watch the documentation i linked there are many examples providing solutions to this :)

Comment: You absolutely can use the option tag with angular, just not when ng-option is specified on the select.

Answer (score 2):

see we have to use `<select ng-options="..."></select>`

as per the angular js documentation or

we have to apply workaround for it by adding `ng-selected` directive of angular js so your code will be

```
<select class="form-control ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" ng-   model="brand.is_anchor">
  <option value="? boolean:false ?"></option>
  <option value="true" ng-selected="brand.is_anchor == true">Yes</option>
  <option value="false" >No</option>
</select>
```

This extra workaround we have to apply if we dont want to use

```
<select ng-options="..."></select>
```